# Matlab connection with Java daemon running in Java

Tags: java, linux, matlab, tcp, daemon

I am having problems with the interconnection between two modules of my system, I hope you can help me.

My hardware is:

- Desktop computer running Windows.
- Linux server that runs a Java daemon.

I have a Java app that connects to the daemon and shares information properly, basically it is a TCP connection, but it creates objects to operate with the send, receive methods.

However, it is mandatory for other reasons to send and receive data from Matlab to the server, and viceversa.

I have never used Matlab for connections, so I was wondering if you know how can I connect these modules.

I have thought about including the Java code into Matlab, but I am doubting about its feasibility, as it uses very particular libraries.

I also thought about using tcpip Matlab Function, but I think it won't work.

Thank you for your help!

George.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, basically there's only three options:

1. Use `tcpip` - if the corresponding toolbox is available.
2. Use Java: This should be straightforward - you could either use the standard java environment to open sockets and perform the read/write operations or try to include your own java libraries.
3. Implement the connection in C/C++ and include it via mex - which seems to be the most inconvenient alternative.

Given that you seem to have working Java classes doing your work, option 2 seems to be the best approach, imho.
Including third party libraries in MATLAB usually can work pretty good.
For a start, see e.g.:

http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_external/bringing-java-classes-and-methods-into-matlab-workspace.html

I happened to work within alternative 2 using a third party library for object-based communication with some database-interface.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, I also think that would be the easiest. I will try it!